# Unable to open site url in browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created simple basic automation script in Python using Selenium..
Getting unwanted exception.

File:-

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from selenium import webdriver

import selenium as sel

# Data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Web_Automation_Form_Filling\challenge.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")

# browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
browser.sleep(1000);
browser.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Error log:-

```
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Web_Automation_Form_Filling\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/Web_Automation_Form_Filling/venv/Web_Auto_Filling.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/Web_Automation_Form_Filling/venv/Web_Auto_Filling.py", line 10, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated..
Thanks...

Comment: Need to use *;* in `browser.sleep(1000);`?

Comment: didn't understand what you're saying...@CC7052

Comment: Yoou use ";" at the end of `browser.sleep(1000);` and the previous line, Is it ok?

Comment: yaa ';' don't matter @CC7052

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

instead of chrome application try providing the chrome driver instead 
more information on the site : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Sample code :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

Download the ChromeDriver binary for your platform under the downloads section of this site
reference link to download : [chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work (better to use firefox for selenium):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import wget

DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS[
    "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"
] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0"

if browser == "firefox":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
else:
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
        CFG_phantomjs
    )  # r"D:/_devs/webserver/phantomjs-1.9.8/phantomjs.exe"

driver.get("https://tourwebsite")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("login_field")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here in your codes is that you are passing chrome executable path rather than passing the path to chromedriver which is a different executable.

An appropriate version of chromedriver can be downloaded from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) according to your Chrome version.

For more info, you can refer to the chromedriver documentation [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).
And your final code should be something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = 'C:/Users/Avinash/Downloads/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)  
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
#..here what ever you want to do with page here
driver.quit()
```